# Decode a DRACO encoded obj and load with texture info

Tags: javascript, three.js, nuxt.js

I am using `Draco` to reduce my model size. I used `.obj` extension because my models have texture info.  I read on forums that the best way to load texture is decoding .drc and loading model as .obj but when I use dracoLoader.decodeDracoFile() i get an Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: WeakMap key must be an object, got buffer`

My code:

```
loader.decodeDracoFile('file.drc',
                function ( geometry ) {
                    console.log(geometry);
                }) 
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

> the best way to load texture is decoding .drc and loading model as .obj

It seems there is a misunderstanding. Loading a file in the DRACO format is just an alternative to loading an OBJ asset. In both cases, you only load geometries and no material or texture data.

Texture coordinates are part of the vertex data similar to vertex normals or colors. So I suggest you stick to the official [three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_draco) and load your .drc files like so:

```js
dracoLoader.load( 'models/asset.drc', function ( geometry ) {

    // geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // optional

    const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    dracoLoader.dispose();

}
```